# Can I set exception for certain Attribute Error in Python?

Tags: python

I have short question, I'm courious and couldn't find any answer if I can set exception for certain AttributeError.

For example I have this error:

```
AttributeError: 'product.product' object has no attribute 'order_line'
```

And I want to set exception but only for this one AttributeError, so if another AttributeError would occur then I would see error message.

I tried doing this:

```
except AttributeError == 'product.product' object has no attribute 'order_line':
    break
```

But this isn't valid solution.

Comment: you shouldn't base logic off (exact) exception messages. they're not usually stable parts of the API

Comment: I'd suggest to start with https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial.

Comment: Is this a custom object? You could add your own test in `__getattr__` to raise a custom exception that you can catch

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem. can you give us more context?

Comment: But I want to pass this exception because in my case product.product object not having  attribute 'order_line' is expected situation and function should ignore this error and just break.

Comment: there is object product.product which create another object. And there is function which change values of other object field 'order_line'. if value in this field will be = 0 then record will be deleted, but there is possibility to manually delete this record and then this attribute will occure when I will try to delete record by my function, So i want to set exception that when function won't find certain records, (because they were deleted before manually, which is expected) then function will just break.

Comment: _“in my case product.product object not having attribute 'order_line' is expected situation”_ – That sounds wrong. If there are products without an `order_line` then that attribute shouldn’t be missing but it should be `None` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if required message is in exception string.

```
except AttributeError as e:
    if "'product.product' object has no attribute 'order_line'" not in str(e):
        raise
```

But this is not recommended as you shouldn't be checking for attributes based of messages which can change in future.

Better approach would be to check if the attribute is present using `hasattr`

```
if hasattr(product.product, 'order_line'):
   # Do your stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

**As a general rule**, try blocks should be as short as possible to make sure you only catch the expected exception. IOW, instead of:

```
try:
   func_that_may_raise_attributeerror(obj)
   print(obj.attr_that_may_not_exist)
   other_function_that_may_also_raise_an_unrelated_attribute_error(obj)
   print(obj.another_attr_that_may_not_exist)
   and_yet_another_one(obj)
except AttributeError as e:
   # oops, who raised the exception and for which attribute ???
```

You should have something like:

```
try:
    val = obj.attr_that_may_not_exists
except AttributeError as e:
    # handle the case here
else:
    do_something_with_val(val)
```

Note that for function calls etc, you can add proper try/except blocks around the access to "attribute that may not exists" in the function itself and raise a custom exception (eventually with more context infos - ie the object and attribute - as exception arguments) instead of a generic AttributeError.

Now for your own use case, as mentionned by poke in a comment, the **proper** solution is to set `product.product.order_line` to `None` (or any other sentinel value) instead of deleting the attribute. While it is technically legal to dynamically add or delete attributes in Python, this should **definitly not** be done on attributes that are part of the class public interface - those attributes should always exists for the whole object's lifetime.